# Jest test giving error “Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined”

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, enzyme

I have created a react app using nextjs (react 17.02 , next 11.1.0) and going to test a simple form using Jest and enzyme (jest 26.4.2, enzyme 3.11.0). When I import the .JSX file that I want to test in jest gives this error.

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined

  17 |
  18 |     const errorObj = {};
> 19 |
     | ^
  20 |     if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
  21 |         errorObj.error = true;
  22 |         errorObj.helperText = meta.error;
```

here is my jest.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.next/", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy" 
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
};
```

Here is the signIn.test.js file

```
import SignIn from '../../../components/account/SignIn';
import sum from '../../../utilities/sample';

describe("Sum function test", () => {
  test("should sum numbers", () => {
    expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

I’m getting above error after import my SignIn component. Without that test frameworks works fine.
What does that mean? Did I miss something?

Comment: Please, provide the whole component file. The problem is related to how React is imported, which isn't shown.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for your comment and I found that I import React like " import { React } from 'react'; " in one of my child component file and that's the issue.